# How to copy a folder (not a file) during installation with WiX?

Tags: wix

I'm writing an installation code using Wix, and I need to install an entire folder to a certain location, and then copy that folder to several different locations, I could install those same files to those locations using code one by one, but that folder is about 80 Mb in size, so it would increase my MSI size (80 x 3 = 240 Mb).

One solutions I had thought of was compressing the folder into a zip file, and then use the CopyFile element to copy the file, after that, descompress the three folders, but this increases the installation time too much.

Is there a way to do this using native wix code, or is Custom Actions my only solution?
Tnks

Answer (score 4):

WiX's "smart cabbing" reuses one instance of a file's stored data even if it's included multiple times in different directories. See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/6/1/quotSmart-cabbingquot-added-to-WiX-toolset. So you have duplicate authoring but without bloating the .msi.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think about smart cabbing.  Yeah, that's the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it the way that MSI natively provides, you need to author 3 CopyFile elements for every single file that you want duplicated.

The CopyFile element maps to the DuplicateFile table which is processed by the DuplicateFiles action.  It has no concept of **/* rather it requires a 1 to 1 mapping back to the File.File_  table/column. ( File@Id in WiX )

You certainly could decide that you hate this pattern and roll your own custom actions to handle the job but if you do, make sure you handle install, uninstall, repair, rollback, upgrades and so on.   MSI's restrictions can be annoying but you do get a lot for 'free' (albeit not painless) if you use it.

[CopyFile Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm)

[DuplicateFile Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought would be my option using only WiX native code.. but the folder I need to copy several times is the JRE. For some reason the developers of each module (3) of an app need each one their own JRE, so it'd be imposible to map each file.